# Windows 7 not selected as default on boot-up (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, windows

I have successfully installed a dual boot on my HP 248 G notebook.

- Ubuntu on SSD caddy
- Windows 7 on HDD

When I start the notebook it starts with Ubuntu first. Is there a way I can set Windows to boot first by default?

Answer (score 0):

Is GRUB installed? (I would imagine that it is)
If so, I'd just be sure to select Windows when GRUB is open. You should be able to edit the order in GRUB as well, which would solve your problem.